# New method extension not displayed for Clipboard

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I'm try to create a new method extension for the clipboard like this but when I use it the extension "GetDataThread" is never in the available list and it return an error if I still type in.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyProject.ClipboardManager.Extensions
{
    public static class ClipboardExtensions
    {
       public static string GetDataThread(this Clipboard clip)
       {
        var selectedOption = string.Empty;
        Thread t = new Thread(() =>
        {
            selectedOption = (string)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Text);
        });
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();
        t.Join();

        return selectedOption;
      }
}
```

}

This is how I call it:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MyProject.ClipboardManager.Extensions;

...
content = Clipboard.GetDataThread();
```

Error here is: "System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard does not contain a definitio for GetDataThread..

So I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong here...

Comment: You can't create instance of a Clipboard class [*(it has private constructor)*](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Clipboard.cs,4f77555bdf0239c8) and you can only use extension methods with class instance. Thus you can't achieve what you are trying to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extension methods are always extensions to *instances* of a type.  You can use an *instance* of the `Clipboard` type to call the method.  You cannot use the *ClipBoard type itself* to call the method.  There is no syntax in C# for the syntax you are trying to accomplish.